# Java Strings with Delimiters

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I have a string "content/users/user/missions/mission" .I need to get "content/users/user/missions" from it [i.e. string upto the last delimiter] .How to proceed ?

Comment: There are any number of ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I suggest you start with the `String` documentations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: How about you at least pretend to use google first => java split string example

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is that simple then you could do the following:

```
String string = "content/users/user/missions/mission";
String newString = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

There are more fancy ways of doing this, [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) could be one.

Answer (score 3):

Use `lastIndexOf` and `substring` methods from `String` class.

```
String str = "content/users/user/missions/mission";
String result = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: That will leave an `/` at the end of the result.